# How to display node name on mismatch and ignore a namsepace in XMLDiff

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, xmldiff

I am using the below code XmlDiff to compare two xml files.

```
XmlReader reader1 = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(file1));
XmlReader reader2 = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(file2));

string diffFile = "D:\\XMLDiffCompare\\XmlDiffFilename.xml";
StringBuilder differenceStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

FileStream fs = new FileStream(diffFile, FileMode.Create);
XmlWriter diffGramWriter = XmlWriter.Create(fs);

// XmlTextWriter diffgram = new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out);
// diffgram.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

XmlDiff xmldiff = new XmlDiff(XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreChildOrder );
bool bIdentical = xmldiff.Compare(file1, file2, false, diffGramWriter);
```

The xml file generated after the comparison is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xd:xmldiff xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xmltools/2002/xmldiff" version="1.0" srcDocHash="12061993843110569490" options="IgnoreNamespaces " fragments="no">
  <xd:node match="2">
    <xd:node match="1">
      <xd:node match="2">
        <xd:node match="2">
          <xd:node match="1">
            <xd:change match="1">USA</xd:change>
          </xd:node>
        </xd:node>
      </xd:node>
    </xd:node>
    <xd:node match="2">
      <xd:node match="1">
        <xd:change match="1">7909</xd:change>
      </xd:node>
    </xd:node>
  </xd:node>
</xd:xmldiff>
```

I wanted to get the node name for `"USA"`, which is `"countryName"`, and also wanted to ignore `7909`, which is a timestamp. The XML file has many nodes and that's the 
reason I would like to print `"CountryName"` node to see the value.

Also node with value "7909" belongs to a namespace called `tig` as in `xmlns:tig="..."` and I don't mind ignoring everything with `tig` namspace in the document. However I am not sure how to suppress it during comparison.

```
<ContactInfo>
 <PersonName>
 <FormattedName>My Name</FormattedName>
 <GivenName>Test first Name</GivenName>
 <FamilyName>Test Last Name</FamilyName>
 </PersonName>
 <ContactMethod>
 <WhenAvailable>anytime</WhenAvailable>
 <PostalAddress type="undefined">
 <CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
 <Region>region</Region>
 <DeliveryAddress>
 <AddressLine>Address to get </AddressLine>
 </DeliveryAddress>
 </PostalAddress>
 </ContactMethod>
</ContactInfo>
```

Comment: Can you provide your XML? Can't see `countryName` here.

Comment: Hi,It is :

<ContactInfo>
<PersonName>
 <FormattedName>My Name</FormattedName>
 <GivenName>Test first Name</GivenName>
 <FamilyName>Test Last Name</FamilyName>
</PersonName>
<ContactMethod>
 <WhenAvailable>anytime</WhenAvailable>
 <PostalAddress type="undefined">
  <CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
  <Region>region</Region>
  <DeliveryAddress>
   <AddressLine>Address to get </AddressLine>
  </DeliveryAddress>
 </PostalAddress>
</ContactMethod>
</ContactInfo>

Comment: Sorry .Its CountryCode and not CountryNAme.The above xml is the one used in comparison